# SD.open(...) Timeout How can I set it?

Tags: arduino, esp32, freertos

When I open a file, SD.open(...), if there is no microsd it takes 1s before telling me it gave an error. How can I set a shorter timeout?
It would be for a hard runtime software that would have to continue even without the microsd running, and could not be subject to stop for 1s.
I hope you can help me,
Thank you.

I am expecting a solution to this problem.

Comment: long time is usually caused by problems with the SPI bus. wrong CS pin or other device blocking the bus

Comment: The microsd will be used in a rocket. I will never know if something can go wrong or not. So I wanted to set a timeout of 0 regardless of what the communication problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You can see if the SD card is available by using `exists()` for a specific file:

```
void loop()
{
    if (SD.exists("testfile.dat"))
        Serial.println("File exists so SD is available");
    else
        Serial.println("File does NOT exist or SD is unavailable");

   delay(1000);
}
```